How do I free up space on my local drive, but still keep stuff in iCloud?
Platform Macbook M2 Running Ventura 13.6
In response to a comment:
Reading the "Optimize storage" article it would seem I have just two options:

Allow the OS to fill up my disk to 90% of capacity with the  most recently used files. (Optimize ON)

Turn it off, and have it try to keep all of the my cloud drive locally.


At this point I have some 170 GB in iCloud drive.
My mobile documents folder has copies of 120 GB of these.
I need more local space for a project.
How can I force a smaller local cache of iCloud documents?

Two edits would be excellent here. One specify what platform and version of os is running. Two, dig up the how to manage space article and make sure you’ve availed yourself of the basics. Letting us know how you are measuring the space used on the device (perhaps with a screen shot) also may help avoid closing this as a duplicate.

To control how much space your iCloud files takes on your computers local storage, you can follow these two steps:
Verify that "Optimize Mac Storage" is enabled in System Settings > Apple Account > iCloud Drive

If you already had this on, then continue. If you just turned it on, I recommend waiting and seeing if it's enough of a change.
Remove downloads for existing files in iCloud by right-clicking them and choosing "Remove Download." This may require updating to macOS Sequoia (v15) if you don't see this option.

Beyond this, you cannot control how much of your iCloud data is stored locally. You cannot set a maximum amount to download.
